# How to upgrade/downgrade a specific package from "sid" on debian jessie "stable"?

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management

I need to upgrade some specifics packages from *sid* on debian jessie *stable* with their dependencies.

By adding  the following repo :

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

to my `sources.list`, all the existing packages will be upgraded and can damage my system.

How to install a specific package from "sid" on debian jessie "stable"  without breaking my existing system ?

**Edit**

How to set the *pin-priority*  to upgrade ? and how can it be used to downgrade a specific package when something went wrong ?

Comment: The linked question explains how to do what you're asking (including pinning for upgrades/downgrades), but you might well be better off looking for a backport (or asking for one).

Comment: Downgrading from sid back to stable is pretty explicitly not supported. Unless you know *really* well what you're doing, don't try this. Also note that almost anyone who *does* know what they're dong well enough to successfully tries this knows better than to try it in the first place. Try backports instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Going hybrid" with Debian versions is not always worthwhile, (or safe, or reliable, etc.), but *sometimes* it works.

The hybrid version's best case is when a package from *testing* or *unstable* makes only trivial changes, (in perpetuity even), and everything works smoothly thereafter.  Possibly it's already been packaged in [Debian Backports](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/), or some repository or archive like it.

Failing that, provided the package isn't too complex, one can search [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) in hopes of finding something close enough.  The **alien** package sometimes helps.

One could go *upstream* and attempt to compile it, (and package it), but if it's a thorny package this might require more time than one has to spare, (which is why we use precompiled packages in the first place).

The worst case scenario would be a package from *unstable* that's [too needy or quarrelsome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358112/for-a-debian-or-any-similar-packaging-system-find-maximum-number-of-simultaneou), and has too many conflicts with *stable*, wiping out something *more* important than the new package.