# How to downgrade Debian package installed with -t testing?

Tags: debian, apt

I installed an upstream openssh using the [default-release, `apt install -t testing ...` method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253866/23542). Now I wish to downgrade it.

There's a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282058/how-to-upgrade-downgrade-a-specific-package-from-sid-on-debian-jessie-stable) but I believe my question is different because it is specific to the installation/upgrade method I used.

I thought that I could just do it like this:

```
apt install -V openssh-server -t jessie
```

but that still picks up the newer repo. There are no preferences or pins set anywhere.

*I'm interested in whether there's a way to do this. Please refrain from telling me I've made a FrankenDebian system and I'm terribly stupid for doing so - I've already understood that :-)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should specify the desired release *for the package*:

```
apt install openssh-server/jessie
```

The `-t` option defines a priority 990 pin using the given release, so it won't downgrade anything — that requires pin priorities greater than 1000. Specifying a release for a package requests that specific version, whether it's an upgrade or a downgrade (or nothing at all if the given version is already installed).